# SVG and CSS circles in background-image pixelating/aliasing on zoom out in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, svg

I've been trying to create a circles-grid background that can be panned and zoomed in/out. One issue i've been having is - the circles that I create have some issues with aliasing/pixelation when I zoom out (using Chrome 88.0.4324.192).

I've pasted my code below - and if you zoom out in Chrome (e.g. to 80%) the circles start to alias/pixelate and are no longer completely circular.

Is there a way to ensure they maintain their circular appearance on zooming out?

**Using CSS**

[image: Zoomed out to 80% on Chrome]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#grid {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 3000px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 2px 2px, black 2px, white 0);
  background-size: 13px 13px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Using SVG**

I created a circle image as SVG and used this (instead of the pure CSS) but again, on Chrome, as I zoom out the circles become alias/pixelated

[image: Zoomed out to 80% on Chrome]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#grid {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 3000px;
  background-image:  
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='13' height='13'> <rect width='13' height='13' fill='white' /><circle cx='1.5' cy='1.5' r='1.5' fill='black' shape-rendering='geometricPrecision'/></svg>");
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid" /> 
</body>
</html>
```